# Not able to mount my externel HDD to my system

Tags: hard-drive, mount

I'm trying to mount an external HDD for setting up a Plex server. When I try to do this it get the error:

> mount: /home/pi/media: special device /dev/sda1 does not exist.

I found things online about the problem I am having. People said that this has something to do with that the HDD has to ramp up before it will get recognized by the system. I can confirm this with the fact that when I run the command  `fdisk -l`  and it takes a couple seconds before it shows up. They found a fix for this and are talking about a script and put sleep in there. But I never found a script.

I also correctly formatted the drive with fdsik fyi. And Raspbian is installed and up-to-date.

Edit: The output I am getting with the `lsblk` command, [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHqus.jpg). The other output i get with `df -h` gives me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyYlS.jpg)

Comment: Are you getting that error when booting? or when running a mount command manually? or something else?

Comment: When the drive is connected and it wont boot from the SD card that is in it. But when i unplug it, it just boots up fine.

I get the same message when I want to mount manually, so "mount: /home/pi/media: special device /dev/sda1 does not exist." and I use the command "sudo mount -t ext4 -o defaults /dev/sda1 /home/pi/media"

Comment: but `sudo fdisk -l` shows sda1 as existing? another question, does the external HDD have its own power supply?

Comment: It is showing up in the list. And it does not have an external power supply. It is connected via usb and I give power from the I/O pins on the rasperry pi. [this is the module I am using](https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/32791789269.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4dJ3gm3S).

Comment: yeah, powering spinning rust from the pi never worked for me - how good is your power supply?

Comment: I currently plugged it in a USB port on my laptop. But I've had the same problem before using an external power supply for the Pi, this was previous weekend. The power supply I was using is 5V 2A

Comment: you need a bigger power supply - 3A

Comment: I'll try to find one, I'll keep you posted.

Comment: I found a 5V 3A power supply and powered the pi, but it still does not want to mount with `sudo mount -t ext4 -o defaults /dev/sda1 /home/pi/media` and still shows up in `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: Please execute the command `lsblk` when the drive is attached and add its output to your question. You can [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/121611/edit) it.

Comment: I have edited the main post and put the output in there, I'll also put it here for you [output](https://imgur.com/fspxV2r)

Comment: Please add the output as pasted text direct into your question. It is bad practice to follow external links to understand a question.

Comment: I can understand that it is more readable to not use links, but in the comments I can't make anything out of a output. So I feel like it is easier to use them.

Comment: @JasonDeckmyn You wrote it by yourself. To get more/better help you should present your question with information as simple as possible. You burden the reader to have it easier for you. That's not a good approach to get answers for free. And additional information should not given by comments. I have down voted the question.

Comment: well, there is no sda1 in `lsblk` .... so, it sees that there's a device there (sda), but can't read it to get the partition table ... look in the output of `dmesg` for errors regarding the device

Answer (score 2):

The questioner answered his question within the question. To have a final solution I cut and pasted it here into an answer. *@JasonDeckmyn* wrote:

> I found out what the problem was with mounting my HDD. Apparently it was already mounted to a certain folder. I found this out with `sudo mount -l | grep sda1`. But I restarted my system but I messed up the system with fstab and it wont boot any more. I reinstalled everything and it worked fine. I also formatted the drive on my Windows machine to exFAT. I was able to mount it to the folder I wanted.

Comment: If `sda` was already mounted, why wasn't the mount point listed in the `lsblk` output?

Comment: @Seamus Do you ask me? There is no `lsblk` output in the question. I do not follow links to understand a question.

Comment: Yes - I assumed you had followed the link to the OP's `lsblk` output. It's not a clear question as I read it - just wondered if I had missed something.

Comment: @Seamus I am not interested in helping here.

Comment: I don't blame you - it seems like a total waste of time. My apologies for asking questions.

Comment: @Seamus Sorry, you missunderstand me! It is not against you and your questions. It is against the OP who isn't willing to simplify his question and burden the reader to take additional effort to understand him. I spare no effort for you :-) The OP is talking about **sda1** but there is no partition shown with 'lsblk` on drive **sda**. Seems the OP has already messed up his system as he wrote.

Comment: :) All is well my friend... But wrt the OP's question, all that can be done I think is to close the question. I have voted to close it, but 4 more votes are needed.

Answer (score 1):

If `/dev/sda` is there but not `/dev/sda1`, it means the disk is not partitioned, or the partition table is not readable.

Connect the disk to a different system. If it gets mounted and you see the data, then the problem is Pi-related. Maybe the power supply is too weak.

If nothing shows up on other computers as well, you'll have to repeat the partitioning (`fdisk`) and the formatting (`mkfs`) before you can use the disk. Note that you should flush the disk cache (`sync`) after making changes to the partition table, and wait a few seconds to give the disk enough time to complete the write before you disconnect it. Then disconnect the disk, reconnect it, and re-run `fdisk` to confirm that the partition table is correct.

If you prefer a more user-friendly experience, use `gparted`.

Comment: The drive and partition is showing up when I use `sudo fdisk -l`. Device     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type         Flags
/dev/sda1      0 900684224 900684225 429.5G 83 Linux native | this is the output it gives me for the drive.
I can't test if the drives show up on other pc's right now.

Comment: What do you see when you run `sudo partprobe -s`?

Comment: /dev/sda: msdos partitions 1
/dev/mmcblk0: msdos partitions 1 2
| I get this as my output. But I ran the command `sudo mount -l | grep sda1` and I saw it was already mounted to a folder. I rebooted my pi and I messed up my fstab file and it wont boot again. But I got it to work. I'll edit my main post with what I did and realised.

Answer (score -1):

What's the output from `df -h`? Do you see your expected disk [sda1] listed?

Spinning up the disk should only take a couple of seconds, and the mount point should still appear in your OS, even while the disk is power saving and not spinning.

Comment: [Output](https://imgur.com/82Xhjt5), this is the output I am getting from `df -h`. And the disk is not there I think because I am unable to mount it.

Comment: `df` won't show info for unmounted filesystems ... since the problem is the inability to mount the filesystem, `df` isn't going to tell you anything